# FileNotFoundException when attempting to copy file on API 25

Tags: android, file, mobile

I have an issue I've been trying to solve for the last couple of hours but failed to do so. I trying to copy a database from one location to another.
My code works as expected when running my code on a device with android v. 5.1.1 but fails to do that on another device running 7.1.0. Here is my code:

requesting permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

.......

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

.....

and in my activity

```
private static final int PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = 0;
```

....

```
  @Override
public void onViewDisplayed() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the method that is in charge of making the copy:

```
    @Override
public Completable cloneDatabase() {

    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {

            try {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/data/com.a/databases/my_db.db";
                String backupDBPath = "/storage/emulated/0/my_folder/my_db_copy.db";
                File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.e("Error while attempting to clone database " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });

}
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.a/databases/my_db.db (Permission denied)
```

Note: both devices Nexus 5 5.1.1 & Nexus 5x 7.1.0 are rooted.

Comment: Stop hardcoding paths. [Use `getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) for `currentDBPath` and use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` for `backupDBPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points here based on my observation.

Firstly,

```
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
```

should be

```
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

You should request permission when it is not granted, be it denied or others. And I think permission `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is sufficient.

Secondly, you need `onRequestPermissionsResult` function after user interact with the permission dialog. You excecute copy database if user grant you the permission.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cloneDatabase();
            } 
    }
}
```